# Change background color of app visible during resizing webView due to device orientation change

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

when cordova `webView` is resized due to orieantation change, there is a moment, in which webView do not cover entire screen area. That is understandable, also user expecting that. But my application have black background, and background of app, which is not covered by `webView` in the moment have white color and this looks ugly.

There are photo of this problem. It's end of rotation animation, moment before white rectangle disappear. (It is truly moment [a few hundred of miliseconds], so I had to take a photo :-) )
http://oi57.tinypic.com/15f4u4n.jpg

What I tried:

- Set BackroundColor preference in config.xml to 0xff000000
- Set android:theme of application (and activity) to `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`
- `setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` in `onCreate` method of activity after init to `appView`, `super.root` and `getWindow().getDecorView()`
- Black background (of html and body) is already set in css

I really don't know how to get rid of this white shine. :-)

Note: This issue occurs on Android 2.3 and 4.0. Android 4.1 and up does not have this problem.

Comment: Hmm, downvote... Anyone who don't know, how to start Android 2.3 or 4.0 emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did error somewhere, because `appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` (appView is Cordova webView) works. But that, the BackgroundColor doesn't do this for you, is bug in Cordova and is now fixed in the next Cordova version (3.6). [CB-7159](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7159?filter=-3)